# submit search on key enter iterates

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input search box that searches to google and it works fine. What I was trying to add was a function that searches on keypress enter I added that functionality but now every time I click enter to search the function start to iterate and open multiple tabs of the same search. How can I restrict it to only open 1 search tab? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function searchGoogle() {
  document.getElementById("googleSearchButton").href =
    (("https://www.google.com/search?q=") + (document.getElementById("googleSearchInput").value));

  // Get the input field
  var input = document.getElementById("googleSearchInput");

  // Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      // Cancel the default action, if needed
      event.preventDefault();
      // Trigger the button element with a click
      document.getElementById("googleSearchButton").click();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form-group img {
  width: 6%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group ">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="googleSearchInput" placeholder="Search The Web">
  <a href="" id="googleSearchButton" onclick="searchGoogle()" target="_blank"> <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/128/000000/search--v1.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your logic code in side `searchGoogle()`

```js
function doSomething(event) {
  console.log(event.keyCode);
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
  searchGoogle();
  }
}

function searchGoogle(){
var input = document.getElementById("googleSearchInput");
  console.log(input.value);
  
  // Add code here
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form-group img {
  width: 6%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="googleSearchInput" placeholder="Search The Web" onkeyup="doSomething(event)">
  <a href="" id="googleSearchButton" target="_blank" onclick="searchGoogle()"> <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/128/000000/search--v1.png" /></a>
</div>
```